# Echo complete directory

Tags: bash, concatenation

I'm trying to search through a directory to find a file with a specific string of text and echo the complete directory back, but I am getting confused at the output I am seeing.

Current Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/$USER/.remmina/
p=/home/$USER/.remmina/
f=&(grep -ir $USER --label=/home/$USER/.remmina/) | sed 's/[:].*//'
pgrep remmina && echo Remmina is currently running. || echo $p$f
```

Which outputs:

```
1497018901448.remmina
/home/testuser1/.remmina/
```

What I want is:

```
/home/testuser1/.remmina/1497018901448.remmina
```

What makes me even more confused is that just echoing the $p has the same output, but echoing $f results in just the file name, which seems to imply the filename is getting deleted, else it should output twice, right?.

Comment: What is `f=&(`?  In any reasonable shell, that will run the command `f=` asynchronously.  (As it does in bash 4.3.42).  Has a newer version of bash used `&` for yet another non-standard purpose?

Comment: IOW, I'm pretty sure all you need to do is `f=$( grep ...`

Comment: Could you provide us with an example of the file you are greping?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Doing it without the $( didn't work. I don't know why, but I had to put it inside a $()

Comment: You need to put it inside `$()` because you are trying to capture the output of `grep` and store it in the variable `f`.  The confusion is `&()` which is a very strange construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
grep -Ril "searchString" $PWD
```

If you pass absolute path as the starting directory, the returned matches will be absolute as well.
`$PWD` gives you the current working directory, but obviously any absolute path will work.

If you want just the directory portion, use the `dirname` command to parse the string. Maybe something like this:

```
grep -Ril "searchString" $PWD | while read line; do dirname $line; done
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I was wondering if there was an easier way to get rid of the "where the match was found" part of a grep besides sed.

Comment: @BenjaminDennison Glad to hear it. I also added how to parse the directory name.